# Relativistic path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, path-integral

I got totally messed up with Problem 2-6 from Feynman's Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals.
The body of the problem is to find the kernel of a relativistic particle between the points a to b, that is,

$
K(b, a)=\sum_{all\ R}N(R)(i\epsilon)^{R}
$

, where R is the number of reversals of the particle moving in one dimension at the speed of light, i is an imaginary unit, $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal time step, and N(R) represents the number of possible paths with R reversals.
I'm being stacked at the first obstruction, which is to find N(R).
I first come up with the recurrence relation considering an "n by m" grid

$
N_{+-}^{n,m}(R)=N_{+-}^{n-1, m-1}(R)+N_{-+}^{n-1, m-1}(R-2)+N_{++}^{n-1, m-1}(R-1)+N_{--}^{n-1, m-1}(R-1),
$

$
N_{++}^{n, m}(R)=N_{+-}^{n, m-2}(R-1)+N_{-+}^{n, m-2}(R-1)+N_{++}^{n, m-2}(R)+N_{--}^{n, m-2}(R-2),
$

,where $N_{++}^{n, m}(R)$ represents the number of the possible trajectories where the particle is coming out the initial position a at positive(denoted by subscript +/-) velocity and coming in the final position b at positive velocity, with N reversals in the "n by m" grid, and so on.
However I finally find that it's really outta my ability to generalize N as a function of n, m, and R.
I'm not sure this is the ordinary way to find the solution of the problem. I welcome any kinda help for this problem, thank you.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's the formula, although not really a ``closed form'' one:
$$\begin{align*}
K_{+-}(0,0,x,y)&=
\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor y/2 \rfloor}(-1)^r \binom{(x+y-2)/2}{r}\binom{(y-x-2)/2}{r}\varepsilon^{2r+1}i,\\
K_{++}(0,0,x,y)&=
\sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor y/2 \rfloor}(-1)^r \binom{(x+y-2)/2}{r}\binom{(y-x-2)/2}{r-1}\varepsilon^{2r},
\end{align*}
$$
for each $y>|x|$ with even $x+y$, where say $K_{++}(0,0,x,y)$ is the sum over all paths from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ starting and ending with a upwards-right move. See the precise definitions, proofs and references [here](https://www.turgor.ru/lktg/2019/2-Feynman%20checkerboard/index.htm) (both in English and in Russian).

Notice that itself the Feynman problem is getting an asymptotic form for $y\gg |x|$, and it is rather hard for rigorous solution; we are currently writing a math paper on that.